# Loadrunner, can I replay failed iterations?

Tags: loadrunner

I'm using loadrunner to create system users for my vusers, 5k of them at a time 
I get some failures (nothing wrong with the script- stuff going on in the background).

Before I write something to output the user details for each failed iteration to a dat file, I can then use as input for a 2nd run I thought I'd check.

Is it possible to re run a script, only performing previously failed iterations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to understand why it failed, application, state of data, your test code, etc....   If it happens to be the state of the data resulting in an unexpected set of pages appearing then re-queuing the test data for execution again could simply result in an infinite loop where the data used on an iteration never runs to completion and just cycles over and over again until it is killed manually.

If the issue is an application problem, then it's time to fix that.

If the issue is one associated with test design.   Heading back to the state of data issue.  If the response is appropriate for the state of the data but the state of the data is not appropriate for what is required for your business process then the unexpected page which appears is appropriate for the state of the data but unexpected in a business context and as such should be handled gracefully.    This brings us back to a test 101 concept: Every step has an expected result - Check for it.  If your expected result is different than your actual result then you have either a defect in data or system that needs to be chased down.

Revisiting the queue reference above.  If you feed all of your user parameter data in a use once model from a queue then it would be entirely possible to push data that was in an  iteration which went south back onto the queue for pickup later.   Then have users automatically exit when no more data existed in the queue.    This will require a number of items to be in place, including very explicit handling of error conditions/unexpected pages in your code, branching when such items exist, integration with a feed from a queue, etc...    LoadRunner ships with a queuing system which you can leverage, the Virtual Table Server.   Others have used more robust solutions based upon database technologies such as MYSQL or even ORACLE or SQL Server queue tables.   I like RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks James, A very comprehensive answer. I'll take a look @ RabbitMQ .I considered VTS (I've used the old version but not the new); But I haven't found a way to download a sample for evaluation - I dont think its bundled in with the Loadrunner 12 trial. I might try Squid instead.

Comment: just installed the v12.01 community edition - And now have VTS